# post-order for find -exec?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I want to remove certain directories from a hiearchy using 'find -exec'

```
find $rootdir -type d -name target -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I get error messages

```
find: `foo/bar/target': No such file or directory
```

because 'find -exec' apparently works in pre-order, i.e. it does the work first and then visits the children.
I don't want to simply redirect the error messages to /dev/null, because they might be meaningful.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `-d` or `-depth` option

```
 -depth  Always true; same as the -d option.

 -d      Cause find to perform a depth-first traversal, i.e., directories
         are visited in post-order and all entries in a directory will be
         acted on before the directory itself.  By default, find visits
         directories in pre-order, i.e., before their contents.  Note, the
         default is not a breadth-first traversal.
```

Be careful with `-depth`, if you add a number it changes meaning.